# О выражении "разлюли малина"

Tags: этимология

Во-первых, пишется ли оно через дефис, как иногда встречается? Оснований не вижу.
Во-вторых, что, собственно, значит "разлюли"? С "юлить" как-то связано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Как писать**

Раньше писалось только раздельно, современные словари предлагают **как раздельное, так и дефисное** написание (дефис, вероятно, по образу сложных слов, составленных из синонимов). Поэтому решение пока неоднозначное.

Орфографический словарь на сайте Грамота.ру: [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=разлюлималина&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&all=x)

***разлюли малина*** (сниж.)

Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой

**Разлюли-малина, разлюли́-мали́на**
предик. разг.
Употребляется как похвала месту, обстановке, условиям существования и т.п.

2) **Фразеология**

***Малина, люли малина, разлюли малина*** — варианты выражений.

**Прост. Экспрес.** 1. Очень хороший, превосходный, — За полтинник?! — свистнул Яшка. — Дурака нашёл. Я за двугривенный отхвачу — разлюли малина… настоящую трёхрядку (В. Смирнов. Открытие мира). 2. **Очень хорошо, замечательно.** — А ты, Пашка, оставайся, — сказал доктор, хлопая Пашку по плечу… У меня, брат, хорошо, разлюли малина! (Чехов. Беглец). Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ А. И. Фёдоров 2008

3) **Этимология**

Слова ***люли, разлюли*** связаны по смыслу  с глаголами ***люлькать, баюкать, ласкать, нежить.***

**Фасмер:** Люли, межд., убаюкивать, шв. lulla, др.-инд. lolati "двигается туда-сюда."

Answer (score 2):

Не буду повторять за Sharon и Фасмером основные тезисы про этимологию.

Даю только главное.

У Ушакова есть "люли малина", при этом само "люли" трактуется как междометие со значением "прекрасно, здорово". "Разлюли" таким образом есть "улучшенный" вариант этого "люли", с помощью глагольной приставки образованный. Это позволяет считать *"люли"* и **"разлюли"** в "разлюли малина" междометием в роли глагола или даже предикативной формы, а само выражение - четкой идиомой.

Оба написания фиксируются словарями, дефисное мне казалось не более чем следствием исторического казуса, поскольку вышесказанное вроде бы не дает оснований для такой орфографии. Но сейчас  вывел для себя некоторое обоснование. Оба слова "разлюли" и "малина" означают очень хорошо, прекрасно. Ну аналогично жили-были, худо-бедно и другим сочетаниям подобного типа. Тем не менее раздельное написание представляется более мотивированным.